# fft of a timeseries object in matlab

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, fft

how do I take the fft of a time series object in MATLAB ? I have tried using iddata( timeseries.data ,[],ts) , but gives me error saying   "The value of the "OutputData" property must be a double matrix or a cell array of such matrices."

Is there any another way i can do this .
I need to see the frequency spectrum of an unknown signal which is stored as a timeseries object z , in MATLAB . fs is my sampling frequency, length is total no. samples in my timeseries object. 
this code gives me an error saying "vectors must be the same lengths".

```
fs=4.1650e+04
tsam=2.2676e-05
length=749701
frs=-fs/2:fs/len:fs/2
plot(frs,abs(fftshift(fft(z.data))))
```

Comment: is it uniformly spaced? why not using fft? (something like `fft(a.Data)`)

Comment: yeah , I got a series of numbers . thank you so much !

Comment: did that answer your question? see more on fft in this answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13054363/matlab-fast-fourier-transform-fft-for-time-and-speed/13054749#13054749)

Comment: I am not getting the spectral Graph